# Showing a button column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, mvp

In a Win forms application I have a problem with data binding and showing a command button column in the DataGridView as the last column allowing users to save each records after editing the content.

This is the binding part done in the presenter class

```
private void ShowEarnings()
{
    BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
    var wageInfo = _WageManager.PrepareEarnings(_Model); // wageInfo contains a list of earnings objects.
    BS.DataSource = wageInfo.GetEarnigsList(); //Earnings List contained in WageInfo object is returned.           
    _View.EarningDetails = BS;
}
```

In the form_load event I add a command button column to the DGV as follows

```
private void ShowSaveEarningsButton()
{
    DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
    col.Text = "SAVE";
    col.Name = "ACTION";
    dgEmployeeEarnings.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

When the form is loaded the last column is shown with the header `ACTION` and a blank button is shown in the cell (first screen shot). When the `ShowEarnings()` method is called, the DGV is populated and now the button column is shown as the 3rd column (second screen shot). But it should be shown as the last column always!.

How to sort this out please?

Please see the screen shots.

[image]

**EDIT:** if I add the column after the binding it is shown properly. But I want it first!

Comment: Try setting `column.DisplayIndex = lastIndex`

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, didnt work!. The problem is even though its shown as the last column initially, it comes to 3rd column after binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe the `DataBindingComplete` event and reset the `DisplayIndex` property.

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dgEmployeeEarnings.Columns["ACTION"].DisplayIndex = dgEmployeeEarnings.Columns.Count - 1;
}
```